# Total seconds since midnight, Java

Tags: java

I am really new to programming. I am doing an assignment for my intro to Java. In my assignment, we need to find the total number of seconds since midnight and changed this number to hours, minutes and seconds to show the current time. I have small problem. when I test my code, the totalseconds show 0! any help would be appreciated. Sorry the code is a chaos

```
        package clock;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;  // to get current time

public class Clock {
    public static int totalseconds;
    public static int seconds;
    public static int minutes;
    public static int hours;

    public static int test;

    public Clock(int hours, int minutes, int seconds )  {
        setHours(hours);
        setMinutes(minutes);
        setSeconds(seconds);
    }


    // use current time
    public Clock() {
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        long now = c.getTimeInMillis();
        c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
        c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
        c.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        c.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
        long passed = now - c.getTimeInMillis();
        long secondsPassed = passed / 1000;
        totalseconds =  (int) secondsPassed;


    }


    public void tick() {
        addSecond();
    }

    private void addSecond() {
        seconds = totalseconds%60;
    }

    private void addMinute() {
        minutes = totalseconds/60 % 60;
    }

    private void addHour() {
        hours = totalseconds / 3600; 
    }

    public String toString() {
        DecimalFormat f = new DecimalFormat("00");
        return f.format(hours) + ":" + f.format(minutes) + ":" + f.format(seconds);
    }

    public int getHours() {
        return hours;
    }
    public int getMinutes() {
        return minutes;
    }
    public int getSeconds() {
        return seconds;
    }

    // the total number of minutes sinces midnight
    public int getTotalMinutes() {
        return totalseconds / 60 % 60;
    }

    // the total number of seconds since midnight 
    public int getTotalSeconds() {
        return totalseconds;
    }

    public void setHours(int hours) {
        if (hours > 23 || hours < 0) {
            this.hours = 0;
        }
        else
            this.hours = hours;
    }
    public void setMinutes(int minutes) {
        if (minutes > 59 || minutes < 0)
            this.minutes = 0;
        else
            this.minutes = minutes;
    }
    public void setSeconds(int seconds) {
        if (seconds > 59 || seconds < 0)
            this.seconds = 0;
        else
            this.seconds = seconds;
    }

    // reset hours, minutes and seconds to zero
    public void reset() {
        hours = minutes = seconds = 0;
    }
    public static void main(String [] args){

        System.out.println("this is total seconds " + test + totalseconds );
    }


}
```

Comment: You're not instantiating your class or calling any methods. Why would it print anything other than the default values?

Answer (score 1):

Change main to this.

```
public static void main(String [] args){
    Clock clock = new Clock();
    System.out.println("this is total seconds " + test + totalseconds );
}
```

New you make an instance of Clock and the constructor is called, where all your magic happens.

Comment: This may work, but it's not the correct solution as it ignores OP's confusion between static and instance members.

Comment: Thanks, I got it after hours of missing around with the code. Nobei mistakes from my side.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with what @shmosel suggested. There seems to be confusion in how to use instance variable. Further, I think you should take advantages of Java 8 methods for your time part.

```
class Clock {
    private int totalseconds;
    private int seconds;
    private int minutes;
    private int hours;

    int test;

    public Clock(int hours, int minutes, int seconds) {
      setHours(hours);
      setMinutes(minutes);
      setSeconds(seconds);
    }

    // use current time
public Clock() {
    LocalTime now = LocalTime.now(ZoneId.systemDefault());
    totalseconds = now.toSecondOfDay();
}

public void tick() {
    addSecond();
}

private void addSecond() {
    seconds = totalseconds % 60;
}

private void addMinute() {
    minutes = totalseconds / 60 % 60;
}

private void addHour() {
    hours = totalseconds / 3600;
}

public String toString() {
    DecimalFormat f = new DecimalFormat("00");
    return f.format(hours) + ":" + f.format(minutes) + ":" + f.format(seconds);
}

public int getHours() {
    return hours;
}

public int getMinutes() {
    return minutes;
}

public int getSeconds() {
    return seconds;
}

// the total number of minutes since midnight
public int getTotalMinutes() {
    return totalseconds / 60 % 60;
}

// the total number of seconds since midnight
public int getTotalSeconds() {
    return totalseconds;
}

public void setHours(int hours) {
    if (hours > 23 || hours < 0) {
        this.hours = 0;
    } else
        this.hours = hours;
}

public void setMinutes(int minutes) {
    if (minutes > 59 || minutes < 0)
        this.minutes = 0;
    else
        this.minutes = minutes;
}

public void setSeconds(int seconds) {
    if (seconds > 59 || seconds < 0)
        this.seconds = 0;
    else
        this.seconds = seconds;
}

// reset hours, minutes and seconds to zero
public void reset() {
    hours = minutes = seconds = 0;
}
}

public class SecondsSinceMidnight {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Clock myClock = new Clock();
    System.out.println("Total seconds that elapsed since midnight:" + myClock.getTotalSeconds());
    System.out.println("Converted to Minutes: " + myClock.getTotalMinutes());
  }

}
```